# jQuery if currency input field is greater than

Tags: jquery, css, textfield, hide, show

I wrote some code that will hide a field until the value is over a specific amount.

My css looks like:

```css
#main .gfield--type-total {
    display: none;
}
```

My JS looks like:

```js
    if (fieldvalue > 0.30 || $0.30) {
        $(".gfield--type-total").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".gfield--type-total").hide();
    }
```

My total field by default shows $0.30 because it has a formula that's calculating the transaction fee and adding it to the amount. I don't want people to think I'm charging them out of the gate, so I figured I'd just hide the total field until the amount is over $0.30.

I think the code above is good, but doesn't work (I'm thinking because of the dollar sign)

What I'm trying to do is say if amount is 0.30 or $0.30 hide total, if it's above 0.30 or $0.30 show total.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: You can just replace dollar if it's present i.e : `fieldvalue.replace('$', '')` or no  ?

Comment: That would just remove the dollar sign completely and once I do that how do I get the new val without the dollar sign so I could use that val to hide or show my total?

Comment: I did try `var fieldvalue = $(".ginput_amount").val().slice(1);` to see if I could remove the dollar sign from the value and then I could just use the greater than if on the number but that didn't work.

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vqb9hsac/) ?

Comment: `$(".ginput_amount").val().slice(1)` will still give you a string, you need to convert to a number.  There's various ways and some detailed answers on SO.  I usually just go with `$(".ginput_amount").val().slice(1) * 1`

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m, I'll definitely remember that for next time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Swati for the tweak! I added @Swati's code to strip the dollar sign, then added an onchange so this will execute as the input changes :-)

My CSS did not change, here is the Updated JS:

```
$('.ginput_amount').on('input',function(e){
    var fieldvalue = $(".ginput_amount").val().replace("$","");
            
    if (fieldvalue > 0.30) {
        $(".gfield--type-total").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".gfield--type-total").hide();
    }
});
```

Works like a champ :-)

Thanks,
Josh